# swift change @IBoutlet collection images using the .tag not image

Tags: swift, iboutletcollection

I have setup @iboutlets collection with many images but I want to change the images as a collection and use its tag to chose what image will change but I don't know correct code to change using the tag. I can change a label  but get error on images
this is how I change image but I need to do it using the image tag

```
@IBOutlet var Pics: [UIImageView]!

@IBAction func MyAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
            Pics.image = (SandDFaults[Fault])
}
```

I have seen code like I need but this only works on text labels I want to change images here is something like I need

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var outputTagNumber = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}

@IBOutlet var myLabels: [UILabel]!
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    outputTagNumber = (sender.tag+1)
    let myLabels = view.viewWithTag(outputTagNumber) as! UILabel
    myLabels.text = "Changed this one"
    
    
}
```

}

How can I do this with images? not text

hope this makes it more clear what I need thanks

Comment: First of all you shouldn't use capital letters when you name var and functions, it is quite confusing. Second, what is `SandFaults` and `Fault`?

Comment: try Pics[index].tag

Comment: SandFaults and Fault are an array of images with fault as the key

Comment: tried Pics[index].tag and does not work

Comment: `viewWithTag()` should work IF `view` is the superview of the tagged view, is that the case? For the rest `Pics` doesn't manage order, so you can't do it that way (assuming that tag was "index"). It should work with: `let taggedView = pics.first(where: { $0.tag == targetTag }`. But your code is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry if I am unclear I have edited it to be more clear what I need just a way to check what button has been pressed then change related image. I could do this without collections but I have 50 images and repeating code would be bad idea

Comment: You have 50 buttons, 50 images and 50 labels? Don't you use a `UICollectionView`? You could use the same logic than your Labels and the tag, but with that: UIButton: Tags between 1 and 50. UILabel tags between 101 and 150, UIImageViews, tags between 1001 and 1050. Just then let myLabel = view.viewWithTag(100 + outputTagNumber) as! UILabel; let myImageView = view.viewWithTag(1000 + outputTagNumber) as! UIImageView`. But I'd recommend instead a UICollectionView.

Comment: Larme. I don't know anything about UICollectionViews I have only been coding 3 weeks and I've got everything working except this last issue but not sure how to use your code in my code all I need to know is how to change an image from its tag and I can add that to my code?